# Is pooling of StreamWriter.WriteLine Disk I/Os happening?

Tags: c#, frameworks, pooling

I'm trying to find if the .net framework pools StreamWriter.WriteLine()s before writing them, or if it does it as they come and I can't find an answer on MSDN. For example, if I have this simplistic code :

```
StreamWriter sw = [Whatever];
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("Whatever : {0}", i);
}
```

Would this write 100000 times to the disk, or will the framework pool some of them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the value of the [`AutoFlush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) property, as well as the buffer size, which can be specified on construction.

Comment: I narrowed my search to the Write/WriteLine methods too fast and I missed that. I'm ashamed! Thanks sir!